# CSS Animation: TranslateX() in angle/curve?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/9ckqb6t3/3/) here as you can see its moving from right to left, but how can I make it run in some kind of angle. [Here it is integrated](http://googledoodle.lucasdebelder.be/), I want to have it run from the right to the left, in the curve so pretty much on the planet.

It probably has to do something with `rotate(x deg)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an animation on both the X and Y axis, so that it looks like it's on a curve.

Here is a fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kellyking/wug7opqs/1/

The X motion is on the item(dot), and the Y motion is on the :after, which gives it a curve. You an adjust the x and y values (in the keyframes) to change the angle of the curve.

```
dot {
animation: xAxis 15s  linear infinite;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
.dot::after {
content: ".";
display: block;
animation: yAxis 15s  ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

You can replace the "." with your image.

This code was adapted from the examples on this site:
http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/

Comment: FYI: This question will likely be closed as a duplicate of [one the OP posted, which is basically identical](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43263309/3773011). You may want to copy-&-paste your answer to a new answer on the duplicate question (i.e. copy the source text and create a new answer). If done, you should delete this answer after posting one on that question (duplicate answers are discouraged).  You might want to do this process soon, as it is likely that question will be closed as it does not contain a [mcve] in the question itself (required for a debugging question to be on-topic).